# IE9 Javascript slower than IE8 - that's weird!

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I'm having difficulty in explaining why the following code runs **slower** in IE9 than IE8!

Here's some test code that runs smoothly in about half a second in (latest) FF/Chrome/Safari on OS X, WinXP, and Win7 **plus** IE7 & 8 on WinXP (for simplicity I removed the tweak that makes it work in IE6).

For some reason I can't explain, it's awful in IE9, slow and clunky.  Reducing the time for the setTimeout makes it a bit quicker but no less jerky.

I've tried removing and benchmarking a number of what might be the choke points (Math.min for example ... all with no change.

I'm stumped ... can anyone please point me in the right direction?... preferably one that does not require browser-sniffing?

Here's the test code ...

```
<div id = 'panel' class='noShow' style='background-color: #aaa;'>
    <div id = 'wrapper' class='slideWrapper'>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    </div>
</div>


<script type = 'text/javaScript'>

    var e = document.getElementById('panel');
    var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    w.style.overflow = 'hidden';                                                
    w.style.height = '1px'; 
    var sh = w.scrollHeight;
    show();
    function show()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
           {
                w.style.height = Math.min(sh, (w.offsetHeight + Math.ceil(sh/15))) + 'px';  
                if(
                     (w.offsetHeight < sh)
                ) 
                {
                    show(e);
                }
                else 
                {
                    w.style.height = 'auto'; 
                }                       
        }, 20); 
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

IE9 defaults to software rendering on VMware Virtual Machines (as of 7/8/2011)  there is supposed to be a hotfix released in the near future but no timeline is given per this [blog post](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2011/03/13/internet-explorer-9-hardware-acceleration-and-third-party-hypervisors.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this @TodK ... very helpful... I guess this explains it

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the 64 bit version of IE 9 or the 32 bit version? The 64 bit version is not running Chakra which is the optimized JavaScript engine from the 32 bit version

Comment: Good question ... thanks for the reminder.  Win7 64 bit within VMWare Fusion 3 ... apologies for the omission.

Comment: Ah!... good question... Win7 64bit within VMWare Fusion 3 ... apologies for omitting that data.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry for the double-post ... I hit <enter>!  I guess that might be my explanation.  I'll download the 32 bit version and try that and report back ... might be a few days though.

Comment: I mean the 32 bit version of IE 9, you can run that no problem on win 7 64 bit

Comment: Ah ... that's new to me ... I'll check and report

Comment: I'm feeling foolish here... I can't determine which version of IE9 I have and I can't see how to download a 32bit version of it.  Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: OK... I found it (C:/Program Files(x86) according to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/i-have-windows-7-64-bit-and-need-to-use-internet/babaa5f8-ff06-4ea2-aef6-a9416d65f981 ... but this seems to make no difference.

Comment: @GeeBee In Windows 7/x64 the Task Manager will display a "*" at the end of 32-bit process names -- a quick way to tell which bitness a running executable is.

Comment: Thanks @pst - very helpful for us reformed WinXP users who gave up PCs after Vista! ... this confirms that the weirdness still occurs in 32 bit IE9 in 64 bit Win7 in a VMWare Fusion 3 virtual machine ... can anyone out there test in native Win7, either 32 or 64 bit please?

Answer (score 1):

There are always odd performance variations when running in a virtualized environment. The selection of drivers and how the software offloads the processing will have an impact. Have you tried updating the drivers on your system?