# IE9 Loading JQuery Extremely slowly, all other browsers work very quickly

Tags: jquery, validation, css, internet-explorer-9

The following site works well in most browsers part from IE9. The scripts take roughtly a minute to load?

http://www.charterhouse-aquatics.co.uk/revamp/

I'm totally confused. Any help would be fantastic.

Kind Regards.

Comment: may be it helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589118/ie9-javascript-slower-than-ie8-thats-weird

Answer (score 1):

It is general bad idea (from performance perspective) to put javascript code/css at the bottom of the page, and your page load a lot of it there...

Here is the sample code and tips from Google Chrome Audits of your page:

```
    A width and height should be specified for all images in order to speed up page display. The following image(s) are missing a width and/or height:
    Logo.gif
    tp-logo.jpg
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    image.php
    cards.png
    Web Page Performance
    Optimize the order of styles and scripts (10)
    The following external CSS files were included after an external 
JavaScript file in the document head. To ensure CSS files are downloaded in parallel, 
always include external CSS before external JavaScript.
    css
    normalize.css
    main.css
    tipped.css
    style.css
    buttons.css
    jquery.tweet.css
    inav.css
    /revamp/../layerslider/css/layerslider.css
    /revamp/../layerslider/skins/noskin/skin.css
    Put CSS in the document head (1)
    CSS in the document body adversely impacts rendering performance.
    1 style block(s) in the /revamp/ body should be moved to the document head.
```

In other words, move all your javascript (*.js) include files in the document head section and put before all of them the links to the stylesheet (*.css) files. Also consider using minimized versions of the jquery/plugins/css files, if you cannot obtain such versions, you can use a web service to convert the files for you, [check here, the YUI compressor](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/).

Comment: Hi,I have moved all scripts to the head with zero performance improvements. Any ideas why IE9 would have such a slow load time? Thanks for the help

Comment: Strange, my loading time (IE9) is a little slower that other (Chrome) browser...Try disabling *.js files one by one and see if there will be improvement, this way you`ll know which plugin causes the slowdown...

Comment: Hi, I did exactly that and could not work out which script seems to be causing the problem. Jquery simply does not even load in some cases. Is there any other IE debug tool of than F12 which I find difficult ot use. Thank you.

Comment: Try this free tool, which I use in such extreme situations, it is called IETester, http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: Thanks, I've used it before. Only tells me what I know already.....thanks anyways for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the network information given by the IE9 developer tool, you have a lot of requests for PIE.htc that return 404. I guess that IE tries to fetch the file again for each style rule that uses `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` and in `revamp/css/W.inav.css.pagespeed.cf.o5re9TDSo5.css` you have 9 occurrences (IE also seems to retry getting the file a couple of times).

So either put your PIE.htc file in the css folder, or change to the correct URL at each style rule.

This seems to be the problem from what I can see. If you fix this issue and the problem persist I would be happy to take another look at the problem.